# Error instalacion Pygame en python

Tags: python-3.7, pygame, instalacion, spyder

Sistema operativo Windows 7 64
He intentado instalar el paquete pygame a python de version 3.7 el que uso en el IDLE spyder 4 que se instala con anaconda.
La instalacion fue intentada a traves del anaconda prompt con la sentencia; 
"conda install -c cogsci pygame"

el cual retorno :

***(base) C:\Users\pc>conda install -c cogsci pygame
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible so
lve.
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.\
Examining python=3.7:   0%|                              | 0/2 [00:00 python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*']
Your python: python=3.7
If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked
 for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is s
omehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda wil
l not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly sp
ecify
that.***

Que debo hacer para lograr instalar pygame?
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Eso es porque tienes instalado python version 3.7 y conda acepta para instalar pygame entre la 2.5 y la 3.5. aunque si conda es un framework de python (asumo eso ya que no uso mucho python,  entonces por que mejor no intentar la instalacion normal de pygame) ?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta:

`pip install wheel pygame`

Comment: Se logro instalar esto que me indicas pero aun no me reconoce el modulo pygame en spyder

Comment: Tal vez esta pregunta te sea de ayuda https://askubuntu.com/q/891585

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar escribir **pip3 install pygame**, a mi me funcionó en Spyder 5 con Python 3.8.
Comentario:

1. Intenté instalar con *conda install pygame*, pero no me funcionó.
2. Al parecer es un error que ocurre con las versiones actuales de Python.